# Stop execution until the preceding method is done?

Tags: objective-c, ios5.1

I have an IBAction and it looks like this.

```
- (IBAction) onPressed: (id) sender {

   [self openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady];

   if (AmIReady == YES)
   {
      [self doMyWork];
   }
}
```

Right now, this doesn't work. `AmIReady` is a boolean and it changes to `YES` in `openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady`. The thing is, before `AmIReady` becomes `YES`, this chunk of code

```
if (AmIReady == YES)
{
   [self doMyWork];
}
```

gets called and `doMyWork` never gets invoked. How can I make this method wait until it finishes `[self openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady]`?

EDIT:

Here is what I have in `openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady`

```
- (void) openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady
{
    MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
    mvc.delegate  = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:mvc animated:YES];
    [mvc release];
    amIReady = YES;
}
```

Also in this delegate (MyViewCrontroller), it requires user's input. If the user input has been entered, I need to run `doMyWork`.

Comment: It already does wait.

Comment: if you are not running that method on another thread then that function will finish before it gets to the if statement

Comment: it should wait; anyways, can you post code for `openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady`?

Comment: @rocky:+1 You are correct, i faced many a times similar kind of problem while developing for osx, as you haven't mentioned your target(osx or ios).

Comment: We would need to see the source of `openMyDelegateToSeeIfIAmReady` in order to answer this question.

Comment: please use ARC             .

Comment: as the others say, it already waits... although `presentModalViewController:animated:` will kick off an animation which will not be completed when that method returns. Do you want to wait for the modal view controller to be completely presented? This is the wrong approach...

Comment: @nielshot This project needs to be done without ARC unfortunately. I am not used to it either.

Comment: not used to it: no time like the present! ARC will (mostly) save you lots of work and memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have some code run after your modal view controller has been presented, use `-[ UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]` and pass a block to the 'completion' argument.

(This method is the replacement for `presentModalViewController:animated:`)

Change your code to:

```
-(IBAction)onPressed:(id)sender 
{
    MyViewController * controller = [ [ MyViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil ];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [ self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{
        [ self doMyWork ] ;
    }]
}
```

Comment: Very close. I am actually trying to run `doMyWork` after my modal view controller has been `viewWillDisappear:`ed as opposed to `viewWillAppear:`ed

Comment: then you need to have your model view controller send a message to your delegate after it is dismissed...